# Check for range of characters in a random string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, forms, validation, passwords

I have this function to generate a random password.

My question is How do I ensure that a selected range of letters/sign/numbers is included in the result?

As an example, if I select that there must be numbers or signs in the result string, how do I check if there is at least one number or sign in the result. I have toughed about looping through numbers or signs for each member of the result, and then break the loop if I meet a character I am testing for.

The code snippet works, but without validating the result

```
function generatePassword() {
    var base = "";
    var result = "";
    
    var latinLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    var cyrillicLetters = "БбВвГгДдЕеЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЬьЮюЯя"
    var greekLetters = "ΑαΒβΓγΔδΕεΖζΗηΘθΙιΚκΛλΜμΝνΞξΟοΠπΡρΣσςΤτΥυΦφΧχΨψΩω"
    var numbersLetters = "1234567890"
    var signsLetters = "/|()1{}[]?-_+~<>!I;:,^`.$@B%&WM*"
    var armenianLetters = "աբգդեզէըթժիլխծկհձղճմյնշոչպջռսվտրցւփքօֆուև"
    var hangulLetters = "ㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅅㅇㅈㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎㅏㅑㅓㅕㅗㅛㅜㅠㅡㅣ"
    var nordicLetters = "AaÁáBbCcDdÐðEeÉéFfGgHhIiÍíJjKkLlMmNnOoÓóPpRrSsTtUuÚúVvWwXxYyÝýZzÞþÆæÖöZzÄäØøÅå"
    var arabicLetters = "ءي و ه ن م لك ق ف غ ع ظ ط ض ص ش س ز ر ذ د خ ح ج ث ت ب ا"
    var georgianLetters = "აბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰ"
    var ethiopianLetters = "ሀለሐመሠረሰቀበተኀነአከወዐዘየደገጠጸፀፈጰፐ"
    var thaanaLetters = "ހށނރބޅކއވމފދތލގސޑޒޓޔޕޖޗޘޙޚޛޜޝޞޟޠޡޢޣޤޥަ ީ   ު   ޫ   ެ   ޭ   ޮ   ޯޱ"
    var hanziLetters = "ぁあぃいぅうぇえぉおかがきぎくぐけげこごさざしじすずせぜそぞただちぢっつづてでとどなにぬねのはばぱひびぴふぶぷへべぺほぼぽまみむめもゃやゅゆょよらりるれろゎわゐゑをんゔゕゖ ゙ ゛゜ゝゞゟ"
    
    // input
    var length = document.getElementById('pwLength').value
    var latin = document.getElementById('latinChecked')
    var numbers = document.getElementById('numbersChecked')
    var signs = document.getElementById('signsChecked')
    var nordic = document.getElementById('nordicChecked')
    var cyrillic = document.getElementById('cyrillicChecked')
    var greek = document.getElementById('greekChecked')
    var armenian = document.getElementById('armenianChecked')
    var hangul = document.getElementById('hangulChecked')
    var arabic = document.getElementById('arabicChecked')
    var georgian = document.getElementById('georgianChecked')
    var ethiopian = document.getElementById('ethiopianChecked')
    var thaana = document.getElementById('thaanaChecked')
    var hanzi = document.getElementById('hanziChecked')
    
    // build source string
    if (arabic.checked) { base = base + arabicLetters; }
    if (latin.checked) { base = base + latinLetters; }
    if (signs.checked) { base = base + signsLetters; }
    if (greek.checked) { base = base + greekLetters; }
    if (numbers.checked) { base = base + numbersLetters; }
    if (armenian.checked) { base = base + armenianLetters; }
    if (hangul.checked) { base = base + hangulLetters; }
    if (numbers.checked) { base = base + numbersLetters; }
    if (nordic.checked) { base = base + nordicLetters; }
    if (cyrillic.checked) { base = base + cyrillicLetters; }
    if (numbers.checked) { base = base + numbersLetters; }
    if (georgian.checked) { base = base + georgianLetters; }
    if (ethiopian.checked) { base = base + ethiopianLetters; }
    if (thaana.checked) { base = base + thaanaLetters; }
    if (hanzi.checked) { base = base + hanziLetters; }   
    
    // fill result
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * base.length);
        result = result + base.charAt(rand);
    }
       
    // write to html
    document.getElementById("productX").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this process:

- Select exactly one random character from each character set that was selected
- Select the remaining needed characters from all available characters
- Concatenate all of the above and shuffle randomly

Here is an implementation:

```js
// Some utility functions on Math.random
const randInt = end => Math.floor(Math.random() * end);
const randomOf = (array, length=1) => Array.from({length}, () =>
    array[randInt(array.length)]
);

function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = randInt(i + 1);
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

const groups = {
    latin: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    cyrillic: "БбВвГгДдЕеЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЬьЮюЯя",
    greek: "ΑαΒβΓγΔδΕεΖζΗηΘθΙιΚκΛλΜμΝνΞξΟοΠπΡρΣσςΤτΥυΦφΧχΨψΩω",
    numbers: "1234567890",
    signs: "/|()1{}[]?-_+~<>!I;:,^`.$@B%&WM*",
    armenian: "աբգդեզէըթժիլխծկհձղճմյնշոչպջռսվտրցւփքօֆուև",
    hangul: "ㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅅㅇㅈㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎㅏㅑㅓㅕㅗㅛㅜㅠㅡㅣ",
    nordic: "AaÁáBbCcDdÐðEeÉéFfGgHhIiÍíJjKkLlMmNnOoÓóPpRrSsTtUuÚúVvWwXxYyÝýZzÞþÆæÖöZzÄäØøÅå",
    arabic: "ءي و ه ن م لك ق ف غ ع ظ ط ض ص ش س ز ر ذ د خ ح ج ث ت ب ا",
    georgian: "აბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰ",
    ethiopian: "ሀለሐመሠረሰቀበተኀነአከወዐዘየደገጠጸፀፈጰፐ",
    thaana: "ހށނރބޅކއވމފދތލގސޑޒޓޔޕޖޗޘޙޚޛޜޝޞޟޠޡޢޣޤޥަ ީ   ު   ޫ   ެ   ޭ   ޮ   ޯޱ",
    hanzi: "ぁあぃいぅうぇえぉおかがきぎくぐけげこごさざしじすずせぜそぞただちぢっつづてでとどなにぬねのはばぱひびぴふぶぷへべぺほぼぽまみむめもゃやゅゆょよらりるれろゎわゐゑをんゔゕゖ ゙ ゛゜ゝゞゟ",
};

function generatePassword(length, charGroups) {
    if (charGroups.length > length) {
        throw "Required length incompatible with number of character groups";
    }
    // Select one from each set, and take the rest from any in those sets. Then shuffle.
    return shuffle([
        ...charGroups.flatMap(group => randomOf(groups[group])),
        ...randomOf(charGroups.map(group => groups[group]).join(""), length - charGroups.length)
     ]).join("");
}

// I/O handing:

function clickHandler() {
    // Get inputs
    const length = +document.getElementById('pwLength').value;
    const selected = Object.keys(groups).filter(group => document.getElementById(group + "Checked").checked);
    // Apply random generation based on these parameters
    const result = generatePassword(length, selected);
    // Output:
    document.getElementById("productX").textContent = result;
}

document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

```css
#pwLength { width: 4em }
#productX { font-family: monospace }
```

```html
Length: <input id="pwLength" type="number" value="16">
<table><tr>
    <td><input id="latinChecked" type="checkbox" checked>Latin</td>
    <td><input id="cyrillicChecked" type="checkbox">Cyrillic</td>
    <td><input id="greekChecked" type="checkbox">Greek</td>
    <td><input id="numbersChecked" type="checkbox" checked>Numbers</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="signsChecked" type="checkbox" checked>Signs</td>
    <td><input id="armenianChecked" type="checkbox">Armenian</td>
    <td><input id="hangulChecked" type="checkbox">Hangul</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="nordicChecked" type="checkbox">Nordic</td>
    <td><input id="arabicChecked" type="checkbox">Arabic</td>
    <td><input id="georgianChecked" type="checkbox">Georgian</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input id="ethiopianChecked" type="checkbox">Etheopian</td>
    <td><input id="thaanaChecked" type="checkbox">Thaana</td>
    <td><input id="hanziChecked" type="checkbox">Hanzi</td>
</tr></table>
<button id="generate">Generate password</button><br>
Password: <span id="productX"></span>
```

Comment: Nice touch with the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm, I didn't.

I don't see how it is validated that at least one character of the selected strings is represented in the result, since characters and numbers are only a small part of the characters that can be chosen.

Comment: Two selections are made: the first one ensures one character of each set is selected. So that is assured. The second selection (`sample()`) will take care of randomly selecting characters more freely.

Comment: This has the -- somewhat surprising for passwords -- feature that no character can appear more than twice, once in the *group* stage and once in the *all* stage.

Comment: @Scott, right, that is indeed not standard behaviour. Thanks for pointing at that. I have removed that logic, now allowing duplicate selections in that *all* stage.

Comment: Nice, and it comes with a minor simplification too!  An alternative factoring would make `generatePassword` a pure function from an array of alphabet strings to a single string, leaving the DOM-checking and alphabet selection in a smaller side-effects function.

Comment: @Scott, separation of concern implemented ;-)

Comment: Very nice.  I wish I could upvote again!

Answer (score 0):

I will add this method, to check if a selected sequences of letters is included

```
if (latin.checked) { 
        var check = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i > result.length; i++) {
            if (latinLetter.includes.includes(result.charAt(i))) {
                i = result.length + 1;
                check++;
            } 
            if (check == 0) { generatePassword(); }
        } 
    }
```

Regarding avoiding repeated characters as @Scott mentioned

```
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * base.length);
        result = result + base.charAt(rand);
        xLetter = xLetter.slice(rand, rand + 1); 
    }
```

But i guess that it would be better to just avoid repeating the last character

```
  var last;

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * base.length);

        if ( last == base.charAt(rand) ) {
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * base.length);
        }

        if ( last == base.charAt(rand).toLowerCase() ) {
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * base.length);
        }
        
        if ( last == base.charAt(rand).toUpperCase() ) {
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * base.length);
        }
        
        last = base.charAt(rand);
        // can be equal to the last character, but the probability is low
        result = result + base.charAt(rand);
    }

    if (latin.checked) { 
        var check = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i > result.length; i++) {
            if (latinLetter.includes.includes(result.charAt(i))) {
                i = result.length + 1;
                check++;
            } 
            if (check == 0) { generatePassword(); }
        } 
    }

    // is upper
    var upperCheck = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i > result.length; i++) {
        if (result.charAt(i) == result.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
            i = result.length + 1;
            upperCheck++;
        } 
       if (upperCheck == 0) { generatePassword(); }
    }
    
    // is upper
    var lowerCheck = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i > result.length; i++) {
        if (result.charAt(i) == result.charAt(i).toLowerCase()) {
            i = result.length + 1;
            lowerCheck++;
        } 
        if (lowerCheck == 0) { generatePassword(); }
    }
```